# Inner Join with more than a field

Tags: subsonic, inner-join

Precise to do a select with inner join that has relationship in more than a field among the tables

Exemple:

```
 DataSet dt = new Select().From(SubConta.Schema)
         .InnerJoin(PlanoContabilSubConta.EmpSubContaColumn, SubConta.CodEmpColumn)
         .InnerJoin(PlanoContabilSubConta.FilSubContaColumn, SubConta.CodFilColumn)
         .InnerJoin(PlanoContabilSubConta.SubContaColumn, SubConta.TradutorColumn)
         .Where(PlanoContabilSubConta.Columns.EmpContabil).IsEqualTo(cEmp)
         .And(PlanoContabilSubConta.Columns.FilContabil).IsEqualTo(cFil)
         .And(PlanoContabilSubConta.Columns.Conta).IsEqualTo(cTrad)
         .ExecuteDataSet();
```

But the generated sql is wrong:

```
exec sp_executesql N'/* GetDataSet() */ SELECT [dbo].[SubContas].[CodEmp], [dbo].[SubContas].[CodFil], [dbo].[SubContas].[Tradutor], [dbo].[SubContas].[Descricao], [dbo].[SubContas].[Inativa], [dbo].[SubContas].[DataImplantacao]

 FROM [dbo].[SubContas]
 INNER JOIN [dbo].[PlanoContabilSubContas] ON [dbo].[SubContas].[CodEmp] = [dbo].[PlanoContabilSubContas].[EmpSubConta]
 INNER JOIN [dbo].[PlanoContabilSubContas] ON [dbo].[SubContas].[CodFil] = [dbo].[PlanoContabilSubContas].[FilSubConta]
 INNER JOIN [dbo].[PlanoContabilSubContas] ON [dbo].[SubContas].[Tradutor] = [dbo].[PlanoContabilSubContas].[SubConta]
 WHERE EmpContabil = @EmpContabil0
 AND FilContabil = @FilContabil1
 AND Conta = @Conta2
',N'@EmpContabil0 varchar(1),@FilContabil1 varchar(1),@Conta2 varchar(1)',@EmpContabil0='1',@FilContabil1='1',@Conta2='1'
```

What should be made to generate this sql?

```
exec sp_executesql N'/* GetDataSet() */ SELECT [dbo].[SubContas].[CodEmp], [dbo].[SubContas].[CodFil], [dbo].[SubContas].[Tradutor], [dbo].[SubContas].[Descricao], [dbo].[SubContas].[Inativa], [dbo].[SubContas].[DataImplantacao]

     FROM [dbo].[SubContas]
     INNER JOIN [dbo].[PlanoContabilSubContas] ON [dbo].[SubContas].[CodEmp] = [dbo].[PlanoContabilSubContas].[EmpSubConta] AND
     [dbo].[SubContas].[CodFil] = [dbo].[PlanoContabilSubContas].[FilSubConta] AND
     [dbo].[SubContas].[Tradutor] = [dbo].[PlanoContabilSubContas].[SubConta]
     WHERE EmpContabil = @EmpContabil0
     AND FilContabil = @FilContabil1
     AND Conta = @Conta2
    ',N'@EmpContabil0 varchar(1),@FilContabil1 varchar(1),@Conta2 varchar(1)',@EmpContabil0='1',@FilContabil1='1',@Conta2='1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can't join on multiple columns in SubSonic 2, you could just create a SQL view that joins as you want it to and then get SubSonic to generate a model for that view.